# Seperating a Model into Meshes for Depth Ordered Rendering

Tags: graphics, rendering, blender, 3dsmax, assimp

So I have one big mesh which models a building. I would like to chop the mesh into parts by floor and hallway to make geographically distinct "scenes" which I can cull/order before rendering to reduce render time. I used 3DS Max to "Slice" the model into various meshes however in the scene explorer it still only shows 1 object. When I export the scene to fbx and read it in Assimp it only reads in 1 mesh.

**TLDR**: How do I split a model in 3DS Max (or similar) such that it exports as multiple meshes which I can selectively render?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on another Stack Exchange site, such as Graphic Design, rather than here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to "Slice" the model, in my case I used the Slice Plane to get clean cuts. Then To use a "Mesh Edit" modifier and "Detach" each individual component.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 3ds Max forum post asking the exact same thing.  Hopefully the answer in there can be useful for you too.
https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-max-forum/split-a-mesh-into-several-meshes/m-p/5927179#M109322

Comment: This article is actually what drew me to the slice method in the first place. The part I was missing was detaching the sliced components into new objects. (thanks to u/lucas_3d on reddit for the tip).